# Rails autocomplete does not work with the fields added by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

This is my JavaScript code and I am using for `autocomplete` with the fields of my form and it works fine.

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
    $('.tenpoautofill').autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: '/autocomplete_tenpofield'
    });
});
```

The problem is when I add fields using JavaScript having same class, `autocomplete` does not works .

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution 
I just needed to add autocomplete code to the for loop which is used to append the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Might be turbolinks... try using

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  // ...
})
```

insteead of

```
document.onload...
```